# Updating other player frames for the user. Phaser 3 & socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I have been struggling updating the other players frame for the user playing in my game. I have gotten to the point of having a new player created for each new connection, each user can walk around and the other users can see their updated position in real time but not a change in their direction due to the frame being at 0 which is down in my case.

```js
// socket.js (server-side)
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const players = {};

function initializeSocket(server, corsOptions) {
  const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: corsOptions, // Use the provided CORS options from server.js
  });

  io.on("connect", socket => {

    // Generate a unique player ID for the connected player
    const playerId = uuidv4();

    // Display a message to ensure connection
    console.log(`Player ${playerId} connected`);

    // Store the player ID in the `players` object
    players[playerId] = { x: 0, y: 0, frame: 0 };

    // Send the player ID to the connected client
    socket.emit("playerId", playerId);

    // Listen for a change in the players position
    socket.on("playerPosition", (x, y, frame) => {

      // Update players coordinates in the players objects {x, y}
      players[playerId].x = x;
      players[playerId].y = y;
      players[playerId].frame = frame;

      // Broadcast the updated player positions to all connected clients
      socket.emit("updatePlayerPositions", players);

    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      // Display a message to ensure disconnection
      console.log(`Player ${playerId} disconnected`);
      
      // Remove the disconnected player from the players object {}
      delete players[playerId];

      // Broadcast the updated player positions to all connected clients
      socket.emit("updatePlayerPositions", players);
    });
    
  });

};

module.exports = initializeSocket;
```

This code below is from Socket.js on client-side...

```js
    handleSocketEmitPlayerPosition(x, y, frame){
        this.socket.emit("playerPosition", x, y, frame.name);
    };
```

This code below gets called at the end of my Player update() function...

```js
    this.socket.handleSocketEmitPlayerPosition(this.x, this.y, this.frame);
```

This code below is from my GameScene class (I made a comment showing what line causes an error when uncommented)...

```js
    updatePlayerLocations(players) {
      console.log(players)
      // Loop through all the players sent back from server.
      for (const p in players) {
        // Make sure the player isn't the player playing before creating a new Player object.
        if (p !== this.playerId) {
          // Check to make sure the other player(s) have not been created yet.
          if (!this.players[p]) {
            this.players[p] = new Player(this, 0, 0, this.currentPlayerSpriteSheet, this.socket);
            this.players[p].setUiScene(this.uiscene);
            this.players[p].setEventListeners();
          };
          // Update all the other players (x, y) coordinates
          this.players[p].x = players[p].x;
          this.players[p].y = players[p].y;
          this.players[p].setPlayerFrame(players[p].frame); // This line causes error
        };
      };

      // Remove disconnected players
      for (const p in this.players) {
        if (!players[p]) {
          this.players[p].destroy();
          delete this.players[p];
        };
      };
    };
```

This is the error message I get when running that line uncommented...

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isGLTexture')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isGLTexture')
    at MultiPipeline.batchSprite (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:168652:52)
    at Player.ImageWebGLRenderer [as renderWebGL] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60843:27)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:165597:23)
    at CameraManager.render (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23540:28)
    at Systems.render (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:178756:28)
    at SceneManager.render (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:176411:23)
    at Game.step (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28331:26)
    at TimeStep.step (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29219:20)
    at step (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40276:23)
```

I log the players object to the console as well to make sure the frame property exists and changes when a player moves a direction and it does, and here is the logged players objects output...

```
{57c8f1fa-7b55-491e-b5ec-550975de9090: {…}}
57c8f1fa-7b55-491e-b5ec-550975de9090
: 
frame
: 
16
x
: 
83.33333333333334
y
: 
0
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

How come the program crashes giving the error provided earlier above when using this line of code below?

```js
this.players[p].setPlayerFrame(players[p].frame);
```

I have tried 4-5 different logical approaches and end up getting a relatively similar error when trying to update the frame for all other players showing a directional change for the user. With that line commented out all connected users can walk around and others can see the positional change in real-time but not the directional change. Is it possible from updating the other players frames too often?

Thank you for any feedback provided, been stuck for a bit now.

Comment: The error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isGLTexture')` sounds like there is something wrong with your frame, texture or spritesheet. If you are running this in the browser, you could click on where the error happens in your bundle.js, and then try to add a breakpoint to see on which object it is trying to access `isGLTexture`, and then see if you can instantiate that texture correctly. I see you haven't shared the code where you create currentPlayerSpriteSheet, which is where the bug might lie.